# Load data in file and get a foreign key from an existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Hello there I have a Mysql Table for the Cantons (Switzerland we don't have states its canton here)
I've loaded all Cantons into my table (Local data infile from swiss postalservice).
Now I want to fill in the city table (again Local data infile from swiss postalservice). The Problem is I have to get the FK from the Canton.

The City File does have canton **initials ex: "VS"** and in the Canton it is saved as PK, Name, Initials (ex: 1, "Wallis", "VS").

If I want to fill the new table I have to get the FK from Canton with that information. I don't want a initiales row in the city table.

Tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE tbl_canton (
        PK_canton INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        canton_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        canton_initiales VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (PK_canton)
    );

    CREATE TABLE tbl_city (
        PK_city INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        city_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        city_zipcode INT NOT NULL,
        FK_canton INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (PK_city),
        FOREIGN KEY (FK_canton) REFERENCES  db_eventengine.tbl_canton (PK_canton)
    );
```

I've tryed:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/temp/tbl_city.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_city FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    (PK_city, city_name, city_zipcode, @cantoninit)
    SET FK_canton = (SELECT PK_canton FROM tbl_canton WHERE @cantoninit = canton_initiales);
```

But it will fill @cantoninit first and after everything is loaded in it starts to set the FK. Can I tell MySql to do it after every row or how Can I handle it afterwards?

**ANSWER / SOLVED:**

thanks Denis for pointing to update.
I do it with a temporary table now:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_temp;
CREATE TABLE tbl_temp (
    temp_PK_city INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    temp_city_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    temp_city_zipcode INT NOT NULL,
    temp_FK_canton VARCHAR(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (temp_PK_city)
);

DELETE FROM tbl_temp;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/temp/tbl_city.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_temp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    (temp_PK_city, temp_city_name, temp_city_zipcode, temp_FK_canton);

    INSERT INTO tbl_city (city_name, city_zipcode, FK_canton)
    SELECT temp_city_name, temp_city_zipcode, tbl_canton.PK_canton
    FROM tbl_temp, tbl_canton
    WHERE temp_FK_canton = tbl_canton.canton_initiales;

DROP TABLE tbl_temp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the foreign key, load your data with FK_canton nullable and set to null, update the table to set the fkey in one statement, and then re-add the foreign key.

Comment: I've gone a slightly different path tryed the update first but It didn't work I guess I made a mistake. I am working with a temporary table now: